# Obtaining corresponding MPI version of a feature

Tags: mpi

How can I know in which version a feature is added to MPI? For example, I guess that RMA isn't available in MPI-1. However, this is just a guess and I want to know precisely and as quickly as possible when RMA capability is added. Up to now I used to browse contents of documentations starting from the oldest one to check out whether a feature exists. Is there a better way than this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any feature versioning mechanism in MPI. There is a growing summary of the changes, which is part of each release of the standard.

Comment: No, and you wouldn’t want it anyways because what matters is the implementation correctness not whether MPI_VERSION and MPI_SUBVERSION imply something works. Open-MPI has had major RMA bugs in the past that rendered it unusable for that purpose, and the severity varied by network, so it was a platform-dependent implementation issue. (Open-MPI 4.x should be most good as far as RMA goes.)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to Annex B of latest [MPI standard](https://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf).

If you are interested in future changes you may find [mip-issues](https://github.com/mpi-forum/mpi-issues/issues) to be useful. This repository is maintained by MPI forum and used to discuss future standards.